# How can i upload audio file to Cloudinary with Node.js?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i deeply need help with this audio file upload to cloudinary issue I have had for several days now. I tried many times to make it work, but i am still struggling. I am a beginner backend developer, so please any help is appreciated.

It is an mp3 player App. When i upload a song, the title gets saved in DB, but the **Audio** isn't.

[This is the MP3 PLAYER page screenshot. It shows the title being saved and rendered from DB but not the audio file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIxsW.png)

### Audio upload form

```
   <form class="ui form" action="/albums/<%= album._id %>/songs" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="field">
                <label>Song Title:</label>
                <input type="text" id="title" name="song[title]" placeholder="song title...." required>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label>Song file:</label>
                <input type="file" id="song" name="audio" accept="audio/*" required>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <input class="fluid ui green button" type="submit" id="submit" value="Enter">
            </div>
            <a href="/albums/<%= album._id %>" class="ui small orange button exit-btn">Exit</a>
     </form>
```

### Song model

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

//Album Schema
var audioSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   title: String,
   audio: String,
   date: {type: Date, default: Date.now()}

});

//exporting the Schema
module.exports = mongoose.model("Audio", audioSchema);
```

### Backend code/ROUTE

```
var express             = require("express"),
    router              = express.Router({mergeParams: true}),
    middleware          = require("../middleware"),
    Album               = require("../models/album"),
    Song                = require("../models/songs"),
    multer              = require("multer")

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
  }
});
//uploader
var upload = multer({ storage: storage});
var cloudinary = require('cloudinary');
cloudinary.config({ 
   cloud_name: 'proccess.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME',
   api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY, 
   api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET
});

//Songs new Route
router.get("/albums/:id/songs/new", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  //find Album by id
  Album.findById(req.params.id, function(err, album) {
      if(err) {
          console.log(err);
      } else {
          res.render("songs/new", {album: album});
      }
  });
});
//Song POST route
router.post("/albums/:id/songs", middleware.isLoggedIn, upload.single("audio"), function(req, res) {
    cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path, function(result) {
        // add cloudinary url for the mp3 to the album object under audio property
        req.body.song.audio = result.secure_url;
        //find Album by ID
        Album.findById(req.params.id, function(err, album) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.redirect("/albums/" + req.params.id);
            } else {

                //Creating Album and saving it to DB
                Song.create(req.body.song, function(err, song) {
                    if(err) {
                        console.log("Opps something went wrong!" + err);
                        res.redirect("back");
                    } else {
                        //save the song to DB
                        song.save();
                        //this saves the songs object inside 
                        album.songs.push(song);
                        //save album
                        album.save();
                        res.redirect("/albums/" + album._id);
                    }
                });

            }

        });
    });    

});


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```
  cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path,  resource_type: "video", function(result)
```

Comment: Please add some details or explanation of the solution.

Answer (score -1):

That's because you will need to use GridFS from MongoDB to store data from a file.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#use-gridfs

As you are using Mongoose, please check this module : https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-gridfs

The mongoose-gridfs module wrap the gridfs-stream module, and seems to fit to binary data upload. If you want, you can still do it yourself, by following this tutorial : http://niralar.com/mongodb-gridfs-using-mongoose-on-nodejs/

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. But I have read a lot  about gridFS. I just couldn't implement it with my code. I tried it few times using examples from other developers, but i just couldn't make it work...